# How to access Composite Component attribute values in the backing UIComponent?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, composite-component

We can access the Composite Component attribute values (defiled in the interface section), in the implimentation like `#{cc.attrs.attributeName}`

How can we access this value in the backing component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just available inside any of the methods by the **inherited** [`getAttributes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) method which returns a `Map<String, Object>` with the attribute name as map key and attribute value as map value.

```
Bar bar = (Bar) getAttributes().get("bar");
// ...
```

Comment: I want to access the attribute of the Composite Component in the backing bean of that Composite Component itself. The backing bean will use the attribute for implementing the Composite Component. (I hope you described above how to access the attribute of the Composite Component in the backing bean of the page which uses the Composite Component)

Comment: So, you're talking about the backing `UIComponent`? That's not a backing bean... Just call the inherited `getAttributes()` method. See also our composite component wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. The link you gave is also very useful. Thanks a lot BalusC.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated your question and my answer accordingly to reflect what you really meant and what you really need.